# Resize an image with offset in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

In my computer vision application, I have been doing image operations in this order:

1. resize with bilinear interpolation
2. crop

This turns out to be quite inefficient when there are multiple areas of interest (AoI) in each image, with each AoI needing to be resized at a different scale.

E.g.:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imresize

img_array = np.array(Image.open('foo.png').convert('L'))

# [top, left, bottom, right]
areas_of_interest = np.array([
    [10.0, 14.0, 55.0, 70.0],
    [81.0, 33.0, 170.0, 88.0],
])

# [vertical scale, horizontal scale]
scales = np.array([
    [1.5, 2.3],
    [1.2, 1.9],
])

for aoi, scale in zip(areas_of_interest, scales):
    new_shape = np.array(img_array.shape) * scale
    resized_img = imresize(
        img_array,
        new_shape,
        interp='bilinear',
    )

    scaled_aoi = aoi * np.tile(scale, reps=2)
    cropped_img = resized_img[
        scaled_aoi[0]:scaled_aoi[2],
        scaled_aoi[1]:scaled_aoi[3],
    ]

    do_something_with_img(cropped_img)
```

Is there a way I can invert the order of the crop and resize operations **while maintaining byte-perfect identity** of the resulting image?

If I naïvely just crop and then resize, the resulting image is not identical to the old method, for two reasons:

1. the border is missing pixel data to perform the interpolation;
2. the offset of the AoI w.r.t the original image is not taken into account.

The result is that I get images that look very similar to the original method, but the dimensions are not necessarily identical, and the pixel values are also different due to the pixel aliasing.

I believe that, *in theory*, it should be possible to get results identical to the original method, because of the way bilinear interpolation works.

I *think* I need three ingredients for the solution:

1. include a margin on each side of the AoI when cropping;
2. *account for the offset* of the AoI w.r.t. the original image when performing the interpolation;
3. correctly crop the margin after resizing;

Numbers 1 and 3 should be easy enough, but I'm not aware of any library that does number 2 for me, and I really don't feel like rolling my own bilinear image scaling in numpy or cython.

Does anybody know of a way to get number 2 without jumping through too many hoops? I have access to PIL, the usual numpy/scipy stack, and OpenCV (cv2).

EDIT: Adding a concrete example, run this in a Jupyter notebook

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imresize

def nbimage(data, mode):
    '''Display raw data as a notebook inline image.

    Parameters:
    data: array-like object, two or three dimensions. If three dimensional,
          first or last dimension must have length 3 or 4 and will be
          interpreted as color (RGB or RGBA).
    mode: the PIL image mode
    '''
    from IPython.display import display, Image as IpyImage
    from PIL.Image import fromarray
    from StringIO import StringIO

    s = StringIO()
    fromarray(data, mode=mode).save(s, 'png')
    display(IpyImage(s.getvalue()))

# This is http://www.pdphoto.org/PictureDetail.php?mat=pdef&pg=7917
img =Image.open('zoo_1_bg_012604.jpg').convert('L')

img_array = np.array(img)
nbimage(img_array, mode='L')
```

[image: Original image converted to grayscale]

Define the areas of interest and the scales:

```py
areas_of_interest = np.array([
    [155, 623, 155 + 114, 623 + 134],
    [567, 605, 136 + 567, 605 + 190],
], dtype=np.float)

scales = np.array([
    [1.5, 2.3],
    [1.2, 1.9],
])
```

Resize then crop:

```py
resize_then_crop = []

for aoi, scale in zip(areas_of_interest, scales):
    new_shape = np.round(np.array(img_array.shape) * scale).astype(np.int)
    resized_img = imresize(img_array, new_shape, interp='bilinear')

    scaled_aoi = np.round(aoi * np.tile(scale, reps=2)).astype(np.int)
    cropped_img = resized_img[
        scaled_aoi[0]:scaled_aoi[2],
        scaled_aoi[1]:scaled_aoi[3],
    ]

    resize_then_crop.append(cropped_img)
```

Crop then resize:

```py
crop_then_resize = []
for aoi, scale in zip(areas_of_interest, scales):
    aoi = aoi.astype(np.int)

    cropped_img = img_array[
        aoi[0]:aoi[2],
        aoi[1]:aoi[3],
    ]

    new_shape = np.round(np.array(cropped_img.shape) * scale).astype(np.int)
    resized_img = imresize(cropped_img, new_shape, interp='bilinear')

    crop_then_resize.append(resized_img)
```

Compare the results:

```py
for img1, img2 in zip(resize_then_crop, crop_then_resize):
    nbimage(img1, mode='L')
    nbimage(img2, mode='L')
    print 'Shape of resize-then-crop:', img1.shape
    print 'Shape of crop-then-resize:', img2.shape
    print 'Are they equal?', np.array_equal(img1, img2)
```

[image: Eye, resized then cropped]

[image: Eye, cropped then resized]

```
Shape of resize-then-crop: (172, 308)
Shape of crop-then-resize: (171, 308)
Are they equal? False
```

[image: Claws, resized then cropped]

[image: Claws, cropped then resized]

```
Shape of resize-then-crop: (164, 360)
Shape of crop-then-resize: (163, 361)
Are they equal? False
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the offset of the AoI w.r.t the original image is not taken into account."? Your question might be easier to understand if you included some examples of input and output images.

Comment: @HåkenLid I have edited the question and added a concrete example.